# HTML5 Geolocation on distance callback

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Is there any function available in HTML5 Geolocation  to get the location callback on distance traveled e.g. on every 1000 meter i want a lat lng.

i can use

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

and on the success callback calculate the distance between this and previous point if its greater than 1000 fire my distance callback, is there any other solution?

Comment: it's really just a matter of saving the old pos and doing some math, theres a few good easy-to-find articles out there about doing the math in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to get `lat` and `long`:

```
function initiate_watchlocation() {
    if (watchProcess == null) {
        watchProcess = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
}
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    var lat= position.coords.latitude;
    var long= position.coords.longitude;

    };

    function onError(error) {
            alert_box('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

and keep it in DB and map that to `lat1` and `lon1`, then keep watching `lat` and `lon` and map it to `lat2` and `lon2` respectively. and keep performing below function with old one.

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    return dist
}
```

then perform this:

```
if(distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, K) ==1){
   alert("1000 m");
}
```

Comment: `'K'`--- kilometers
    `'N'` --- nautical miles.